# Returning a null in a .map() versus .flatMap() in Reactor

Tags: java, reactor

The following piece of code works :

```
// emitting employees...
.flatMap(employee -> {

    boolean isAlive = employee.isAlive();

    return Mono.just(isAlive)

            .flatMap(myBoolean -> {
                if (myBoolean) {
                    return Mono.empty();
                } 
                else {
                    return Mono.just(employee);
                }
            });

})
```

But I was wondering why I can't use a `.map` upon processing `myBoolean` (NullPointerException when it returns the null)

```
            .map(myBoolean -> {
                if (myBoolean) {
                    return null;
                } 
                else {
                    return employee;
                }
            });
```

I believe I lack some understanding about the `map` versus `flatMap`

In Java 8 streams I understand the difference between `map` and `flatMap` (for each item received, `map` emits 1, `flatMap` emits N)

But in Reactor I'm a bit confused. I thought that both `map` and `flatMap` emit 1 item for each element received, the difference would be that the `map` emits it as a `Mono` while `flatMap` doesn't. To emit N items, I would use `flatMapMany`.

Thanks in advance for your explanations !

Comment: A blog post I wrote recently on flatMap: https://medium.com/swlh/understanding-reactors-flatmap-operator-a6a7e62d3e95. You might find it useful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From Reactor [java doc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html)

`map`: Transform the item emitted by this Mono by applying a synchronous function to it.

`flatMap`: Transform the item emitted by this Mono asynchronously, returning the value emitted by another Mono.

In all cases, you cannot return `null`. It is simply forbidden by design. The main difference between `map` and `flatMap` is that the second one returns a Mono. This allows to perform an asynchronous call to something like a data base, a web service, etc.

So `flatMap` should be used to performed another asynchronous stuff. It's not very useful if you return a `Mono.just(...)`. We may use flatMap to return `Mono.empty()` in some condition as you did. It is a frequent pattern. Depending on your use case, you may prefer to use `filter` or `mapNotNull`.

Here an alternative code to emit a new object with a condition:

```
        .handle(myBoolean, sink -> {
            if (!myBoolean) {
                sink.next(employee);
            } // else the Mono would be empty ...
        });
```

Answer (score 5):

To avoid NullPointerException in your case you can change map to mapNotNull:

```
        .mapNotNull(myBoolean -> {
            if (myBoolean) {
                return null;
            } 
            else {
                return employee;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

When mapping a content of `Mono` using map method, you cannot provide null as a mapping result, because that will result in the
`java.lang.NullPointerException: The mapper returned a null value.` during the subscription.

The `Mono` can be either empty or it has to contain a valid object.

According to the source code of Project Reactor, the content of a `Mono` cannot be null.

So in this case the valid solution is using the `flatMap`.

Answer (score 4):

That is because `flatMap` will try to unwrap the inner mono in the outer mono. Meaning the value will be null but there will be a type..

On the other hand `map` will transform the `Mono<A>` to `Mono<B>`. null has no type and that is why you cannot do that.

Answer (score 3):

A `null` anywhere in your stream will throw a `NPE: Mapper returned a null value`. No matter `map` or `flatMap`. It is by design.

A short note on `flatMap`: It eagerly subscribes to its inner streams (in your case, `Mono.empty()` or `Mono.just(..)`) and does a dynamic merge as the inner streams keep emitting elements. That's why you can guarantee order with `flatMap`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add filter before `map`:

```
.filter(Objects::nonNull)
.filter(myBoolean -> myBoolean)
.map(r-> employee)
.switchIfEmpty(Mono.empty());
```