# Why does mocking a response of Mono.empty() inside flatmap end in error?

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive

We have a methodA which returns:

```
return bObj.methodB()
    .flatMap(x -> cObj.methodC(x));
```

methodB returns `Mono<String>` and methodC returns `Mono<Void>`.

When using Mockito, methodB we are able to mock, but methodC we are not.

```
when(bObj.methodB()).thenReturn(Mono.just("x"));
when(cObj.methodC(eq("x"))).thenReturn(Mono.empty());

aObj.methodA();
```

When this runs, we get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: The mapper returned a null Publisher
```

When running the application, this works fine, but when running with Mockito, it doesn't. I assume it's something to do with the flatMap, but can't figure it out. Referencing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215810/returning-a-null-in-a-map-versus-flatmap-in-reactor) it seems like it should work, but doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue. What you posted can't even compile: methodB() returns a String, and String doesn't have a flatMap() method.

Comment: @JBNizet I apologize, I had a typo, but you should be able to figure it out. Strings don't have a flatMap, but Mono does.

Comment: I don't have any issue with my code. You have. So do what's needed to get help: post a minimal reproducible example. Don't make us guess what could be wrong in the code you didn't post.

Comment: No reason to be snappy. I posted here to get help and gave enough information that I thought was necessary. Turns out that our when condition was not matching, so the mapper had a null response, hence the exception.

Comment: I understand that. But after you posted the question, and I asked you to post a minimal example, you refused to post it. We don't ask that to be snappy. We ask that because we need it to help you.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm sorry. This was a minimal example that I came up with as the real problem was too complicated to post. I find that if the question is too complicated, it is likely not to get answered. Unfortunately, at a fault of my own, I didn't test the example before posting as I was posting for a friend. But after running this short example on my own time, it compiled and passed in testing, which led me to the reason of the exception: the Mockito expression was wrong. Much appreciation for your help and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: I don't think this should be downvoted. I have the same question and can't think of a more precise way to phrase it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that if anybody gets an issue like this, be sure `Mockito.when` is defined correctly. If it doesn't match, then it returns null. Hence the exception.

On a side note, I had left some information out of my question to make it a little less complicated, but turns out that the example I had described worked perfectly. Reworking through it shown the actual code I had didn't match the when clause.

Comment: That's because Mockito's mocks are relaxed by default: they return default values if the method call is not mocked

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth mentioning (especially since I'm converting code that returns Optional into code that returns Mono and I just realised this) that while Mockito returns Optional.empty() so you don't have to explicitly set-up `when` expectations, it doesn't (out of the box at least) do anything similar for Mono. Mockito returns null and you get NullPointerExceptions.

Hope this helps anyone who stumbles upon it.